# Insert and copy rows based on cell value using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have this table:

```
Quantity   Name
1          A
3          C1
3          C2
4          D
```

I'm trying to make this table change to:

```
Quantity   Name
1          A
1          A
3          C1
3          C1
3          C1
3          C2
3          C2
3          C2
4          D
4          D
4          D
4          D
```

But the result is not as expect: ***Result***

[image]

Pls help my solve this problem.
Thanks!

Here is my code:

```
Sub newrow()
 Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xAddress As String
    Dim I, xNum, xLastRow, xFstRow, xCol, xCount As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    xAddress = ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.Address
    Set xRg = Application.InputBox("Select a range to use(single column):", "KuTools For Excel", xAddress, , , , , 8)
    If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    xLastRow = xRg(1).End(xlDown).Row
    xFstRow = xRg.Row
    xCol = xRg.Column
    xCount = xRg.Count
    Set xRg = xRg(1)
    For I = xLastRow To xFstRow Step -1
        xNum = Cells(I, xCol)
        If IsNumeric(xNum) And xNum > 0 Then
            Rows(I + 1).Resize(Cells(I, xCol) - Cells(I - 1, xCol)).Insert
            xCount = xCount + xNum
        End If
    Next
    xRg.Resize(xCount, 1).Select
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I have edited and formatted your post. So, you can delete your answer for posting codes.

Comment: ok, tks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all …

1. If you `Dim xFstRow, xCol, xCount As Long` then only `xCount` is of type `Long` all the others are of type `Variant`. You need to specify a type for **every** variable!

   ```
   Dim xFstRow As Long, xCol As Long, xCount As Long
   ```
2. Don't ever use `On Error Resume Next` without proper error handling. This only hides error messages but the errors still occur you just cannot see them. Therefore you cannot debug/fix your code. Remove it completely or implement a complete error handling instead.
3. You need to copy the row before you insert, otherwise you just insert empty rows.

I suggest the following code:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub AddRowsFromQantities()
    Dim SelAddress As String
    SelAddress = ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.Address

    Dim SelRange As Range
    Set SelRange = Application.InputBox("Select a range to use(single column):", "KuTools For Excel", SelAddress, , , , , 8)

    Dim fRow As Long
    fRow = SelRange.Row 'first row of selected rang

    Dim lRow As Long
    lRow = fRow + SelRange.Rows.Count - 1 'last row of selected range

    'find last used row within the selected range
    If Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row < lRow Then
        lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim iRow As Long
    For iRow = lRow To fRow Step -1
        If IsNumeric(Cells(iRow, 1)) Then
            Dim Quantity As Long
            Quantity = Cells(iRow, 1).Value

            If Quantity > 1 Then
                Rows(iRow).Copy 
                Rows(iRow).Resize(RowSize:=Quantity - 1).Insert
            End If
        End If
    Next iRow

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: tks 4 your advice

Comment: @hunterx7 did this solve your issue? Then please mark this answer as solution, so everyone can see that it was solved.

Comment: Sr, I forgot mark this. 
I still have small issue.
Does it only work with first column?
Because when I choose column B or C, it didn't work; but It worked when I choose column A.

Comment: @hunterx7 For me it works when choosing column B or C, but Quantities need always to be in column A. Or did you mean to always select the column where the quantities are in?